# Code on Laptop, Process on Desktop

Tags: remote

How difficult is it to set up infrastructure
in which the user writes script on a laptop,
but all processing is completed on a remote processor.

Comment: May be this is only me who doesn't understand your intention, but can you elaborate little more what you want to accomplish?

Comment: ^ also please give some more details about the scripting language and what you expect as output

Comment: So you want to write a script on a computer, and process the results from that script it on a computer ?

Comment: @Hennes "from that script on a **different** computer."

Comment: @Spokey I use Mathworks Matlab/Simulink, but I figured it was best to leave things general for anyone using other scripts.  I expect swaths of raw data files, sometimes graphical data, etcetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set up a Remote connection.  Either download something like [teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/) or go to `Computer->System Properties->Advanced System Properties`.  On the right there is a `Remote` tab where you can select users for remote access. (If you're making money this way, you may eventually need to purchase Teamviewer).

In this situation, technically you will doing ALL of the work on the `Processing` computer but your keystrokes can be done on the laptop.  You can also use Teamviewer to transfer the file to the `Processing` computer after work is done on the laptop.

Comment: So, Windows remote access is the preferred free solution and teamviewer is the preferred proprietary solution?

Comment: Is this ever a preferred approach when considering the lagtime required to transmit results and the less than optimal display refresh?

Comment: Additionally, the only available solution is to work on the processing PC?

Comment: Teamviewer is just really easy, you may have no problem using it, I'm not sure they stipulations for coding remotely.  Like I said above, you could code on the laptop, then use teamviewer or (gmail and RDP) to run it on the processing comp.  I can't think of any easier way to run the code remotely after a transfer than remoting.  Yes you will see some lagtime but it's the closest to 'realtime' that I think we can get.

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine attempting to automate sending your script and ALSO any dependent files. Best to setup another rig and just work on that. Much thanks.